# How to enable compression on the server side with CXF?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm creating a soap webservice client with `Spring` and `CXF`. What is the preferred way to enable logging + gzip compression? Should one use annotations or the directly add the feature programatically?

```
@Component
@WebService
@GZIP
@Logging(pretty = true)
public class SoapService {
}
```

or

```
EndpointImpl end = new EndpointImpl(new SpringBus(), new SoapService());
LoggingFeature feature = new LoggingFeature();
feature.setPrettyLogging(true);
end.getFeatures().add(feature);
end.getFeatures().add(new GZIPFeature());
end.publish("/SoapService");
```

Does it matter? What would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as logging is concerned, [the Apache CXF documentation contains following](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-LoggingMessages):

> Logging is activated by use of separate in/out interceptors that can
>   be attached to the client and/or service as required. These
>   interceptors can be specified either programmatically (via Java code
>   and/or annotations) or via use of configuration files.
>
> Configuration files are probably best. They offer two benefits over
>   programmatic configuration:
>
> 1. Logging requirements can be altered without needing to recompile the
>      code
> 2. No Apache CXF-specific APIs need to be added to your code,
>      which helps it remain interoperable with other JAX-WS compliant web
>      service stacks

So it looks like the preferred way to enable logging would be to use configuration (=Spring configuration file), which should be OK seeing you are planning on using CFX+Spring. I think the same reasoning would apply for enabling the GZIP compression.